# Getting Memory Leak Errors on Server Stop (Eclipse, Hibernate, Spring)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate

When I undeploy wars (Stop the server on eclipse), I get the following logs. All of them are pretty suspicious, but I am more worried about the New Worker #X ones too. I am using hibernate, spring (guice), C3P0 lib for connection pools. Any ideas?

```
2015-09-20 23:05:04.442 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.442 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.443 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.443 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.443 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [commons-pool-EvictionTimer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.444 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O worker #1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.444 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O worker #2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.444 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O worker #3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.444 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O worker #4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.445 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O worker #5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.445 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O worker #6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.445 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O worker #7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.445 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O worker #8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.446 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O boss #9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.446 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015-09-20 23:05:04.447 [localhost-startStop-2] [] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.yammer.metrics.stats.ThreadLocalRandom$1] (value [com.yammer.metrics.stats.ThreadLocalRandom$1@78aa124e]) and a value of type [com.yammer.metrics.stats.ThreadLocalRandom] (value [com.yammer.metrics.stats.ThreadLocalRandom@6597fcc5]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Comment: You have an open session factory instance with connection. Then you stooped server without closing the connection. So webserver will destroy the connection, that's why you see this warning.

Comment: UPDATE: seems like I had open async http client that didn't let the whole thing close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `ServletContextListener` to listen for lifecycle events `contextInitialized/contextDestroyed`. See [here](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/) for an example.

Comment: Well, this logs come only when have Metrics binded as singleton:

    bind(DefaultWebappMetricsFilter.class).in(Singleton.class);
    filter("/*").through(DefaultWebappMetricsFilter.class);



Metrics from yammer (2.2.0)